# Yahoo HTML5 Context Parser - Cross site scripting (XSS)

Tags: html, security, html-parsing, xss

I'm trying out Yahoo's HTML5 Context Parser [Yahoo context-parser](https://github.com/yahoo/context-parser) which helps in identifying potential XSS vulnerabilities.

As a try out,running the **./bin/context-dump**  utility against the text

```
<form><input name=q value="%(query)s"> </form>
```

(taken from 
[ArticleXSSInAttributes](http://ArticleXSSInAttributes))

produces :

```
HTML-State { statesSize: 51 } +0ms
HTML-State { ch: 0, state: 1, symbol: 0 } +2ms
HTML-State { ch: f [0x66], state: 8, symbol: 11 } +1ms
HTML-State { ch: o [0x6f], state: 10, symbol: 11 } +0ms
HTML-State { ch: r [0x72], state: 10, symbol: 11 } +0ms
HTML-State { ch: m [0x6d], state: 10, symbol: 11 } +0ms
HTML-State { ch: > [0x3e], state: 10, symbol: 9 } +0ms
HTML-State { ch: [0x20], state: 1, symbol: 0 } +0ms
HTML-State { ch: [0x20], state: 1, symbol: 0 } +0ms
HTML-State { ch: [0x20], state: 1, symbol: 0 } +0ms
HTML-State { ch: < [0x3c], state: 1, symbol: 7 } +0ms
HTML-State { ch: i [0x69], state: 8, symbol: 11 } +0ms
HTML-State { ch: n [0x6e], state: 10, symbol: 11 } +0ms
HTML-State { ch: p [0x70], state: 10, symbol: 11 } +1ms
HTML-State { ch: u [0x75], state: 10, symbol: 11 } +0ms
HTML-State { ch: t [0x74], state: 10, symbol: 11 } +0ms
HTML-State { ch: [0x20], state: 10, symbol: 0 } +0ms
HTML-State { ch: n [0x6e], state: 34, symbol: 11 } +0ms
HTML-State { ch: a [0x61], state: 35, symbol: 11 } +0ms
HTML-State { ch: m [0x6d], state: 35, symbol: 11 } +0ms
HTML-State { ch: e [0x65], state: 35, symbol: 11 } +0ms
HTML-State { ch: = [0x3d], state: 35, symbol: 8 } +0ms
HTML-State { ch: q [0x71], state: 37, symbol: 11 } +0ms
HTML-State { ch: [0x20], state: 40, symbol: 0 } +0ms
HTML-State { ch: v [0x76], state: 34, symbol: 11 } +0ms
HTML-State { ch: a [0x61], state: 35, symbol: 11 } +0ms
HTML-State { ch: l [0x6c], state: 35, symbol: 11 } +0ms
HTML-State { ch: u [0x75], state: 35, symbol: 11 } +0ms
HTML-State { ch: e [0x65], state: 35, symbol: 11 } +0ms
HTML-State { ch: = [0x3d], state: 35, symbol: 8 } +0ms
HTML-State { ch: " [0x22], state: 37, symbol: 2 } +1ms
HTML-State { ch: % [0x25], state: 38, symbol: 12 } +0ms
HTML-State { ch: ( [0x28], state: 38, symbol: 12 } +1ms
HTML-State { ch: q [0x71], state: 38, symbol: 11 } +0ms
HTML-State { ch: u [0x75], state: 38, symbol: 11 } +0ms
HTML-State { ch: e [0x65], state: 38, symbol: 11 } +0ms
HTML-State { ch: r [0x72], state: 38, symbol: 11 } +0ms
HTML-State { ch: y [0x79], state: 38, symbol: 11 } +0ms
HTML-State { ch: ) [0x29], state: 38, symbol: 12 } +0ms
HTML-State { ch: s [0x73], state: 38, symbol: 11 } +0ms
HTML-State { ch: " [0x22], state: 38, symbol: 2 } +0ms
HTML-State { ch: > [0x3e], state: 42, symbol: 9 } +0ms
HTML-State { ch: [0x20], state: 1, symbol: 0 } +0ms
HTML-State { ch: < [0x3c], state: 1, symbol: 7 } +0ms
HTML-State { ch: / [0x2f], state: 8, symbol: 6 } +0ms
HTML-State { ch: f [0x66], state: 9, symbol: 11 } +0ms
HTML-State { ch: o [0x6f], state: 10, symbol: 11 } +0ms
HTML-State { ch: r [0x72], state: 10, symbol: 11 } +0ms
HTML-State { ch: m [0x6d], state: 10, symbol: 11 } +0ms
HTML-State { ch: > [0x3e], state: 10, symbol: 9 } +0ms
HTML-State { ch: [0xa], state: 1, symbol: 0 } +0ms
HTML-State { undefined - char in html without state } +0ms
```

How does the given output help me to identify potential XSS issues, or in other words how does the Context Parser helps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It tells you the grammar context of each character with your HTML page.

The `state` can be looked up in the [constants file](https://github.com/yahoo/context-parser/blob/master/src/html5-state-machine.js). e.g. 10 means it is a tag name that is being parsed, in your example this is the name of the `<input />` and `<form />` tags.

Knowing the context that something is output informs the developer the correct encoding to use.

For example when outputting user data to HTML, you HTML encode. That is certain characters, such as the lower than sign become HTML encoded (`<` = `&lt;`).

In a JavaScript context you use hex entity encoding, so `<` becomes `\x3c` instead.

In all practical sense, I'm not sure how useful the context parser is in day to day usage. It should be pretty obvious which encoding types to use once you are aware of them. Probably the major pitfall when learning this yourself would be when you have a JavaScript context inside an HTML one:

```
<a href="javascript:void();" onclick="//this is parsed by HTML parser and then the JavaScript parser" />
```

whereas in `<script>` blocks it is just the JavaScript parser:

```
<script>
  // The HTML parser don't run past here
</script>
```

However, once you're aware of this the benefit of a context parser is minimal imo.

So even though it can help with server-side context, it won't help with DOM manipulation and prevention of DOM based XSS:

```
<a href="javascript:void()" onclick="document.getElementById('foo').innerHTML = '(whatever is here should be HTML encoded, then hex entity encoded, then HTML encoded again)'" />
```

(Feel free to try it in Context Parser.)
(The last HTML encoding should not yield any change because hex entity encoded characters `\`, `x` and hex characters do not need to be HTML encoded - however the final context is still HTML.)